# Check if developer mode is enabled in a native Android module

Tags: react-native

I am working on a native Android module for my React Native app. I would like to check if the developer mode is enabled and turn web content debugging in `WebView` on or off accordingly.

Here's what I tried:

```
boolean devSupportIsEnabled;
ReactActivity reactActivity = (ReactActivity) getModule().getActivity();
if (reactActivity != null) {
    devSupportIsEnabled = reactActivity
        .getReactInstanceManager()
        .getDevSupportManager()
        .getDevSupportEnabled();
} else {
    devSupportIsEnabled = false;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile because `ReactActivity.getReactInstanceManager()` is `protected`.

There is also the `ReactBuildConfig.DEBUG` property, but it is always `false` for some reason.

Are there any alternative ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of `ReactInstanceManager` can be obtained by the package if it inherits from `ReactInstancePackage`:

```
public class MyPackage extends ReactInstancePackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
        // store the provided instance of ReactInstanceManager
        this.reactInstanceManager = reactInstanceManager;

        // ...
    }
    //...
}
```

This instance can be used later to check whether the dev mode is enabled:

```
boolean devModeIsEnabled = this.reactInstanceManager
    .getDevSupportManager()
    .getDevSupportEnabled();
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please explain in which file should I write this code?