# How to detect Developer Options are enabled in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

For some security reasons i want to restrict the users who are enabled the developer options. How can i detect in react native?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an [Android solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948720/check-if-developer-mode-is-enabled-in-a-native-android-module), didn't find ios 's.

Comment: Where do i find that ReactInstancePackage code? In which file? @高鵬翔